# Forbid access to code when using debugger in web browser

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack

If I go to the url of the web application I am creating I can see my whole React code under the "debugger tab" when using Firefox. I guess it can be seen in any browser.

Specifically, I go to Webpack field and I can see whatever file/code I want. However, if I go to Reddit and try to do the same I get the following error when trying to open a file:

```
Error while fetching an original source: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

I suspect this is related to source maps. What is the best way to handle this in real production systems? I need to generate maps in order to give them to Sentry. Can I block them at nginx somehow? If this is the way to go of course.

This is my front-end nginx configuration used for serving my React application:

```
  location / {
    # serve bundle
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

Comment: How exactly are source maps being added?  Are they attached to the source file as base64 encoded urls or are they separate files?  Do you see network requests for the maps as URLs or as something like `base64://****` or something along those lines?

Comment: I have just taken a look and when I open a file from the debugger it says at the bottom "(From the main.12r1r12whateverhash.bundle.js" for example. In my bundles I have at the bottom the line //# sourceMappingURL=main.077a21d20f.bundle.js.map which is put there automatically by Webpack. However, I cannot see any network requests for the map files so I do not really understand how this debugger thing works. I believe the debugger might make the queries to that URL to the server to grab the map file regardless what the browser downloaded at the beginning.